# What is the difference between Spring JMS and Spring Messaging?

Tags: spring-jms, spring-messaging

There are two libraries: spring-messaging and spring-jms. They both have got similar classes: MarshallingMessageConverter, MarshallingMessageConverter, etc.

Why do we need these similar libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are not similar. The `spring-messaging` is a set of messaging components which are used in target implementation. The JMS is one of them. Another one is WebSocket.
More about messaging is in Spring Integration: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration. It's just coincident that those classes are named similar. However they are in different packages and serve the same purpose - deal with an XML payload. Although the last one is really specific to only JMS. You may find similar name for classes specific to AMQP protocol in Spring AMQP project: https://spring.io/projects/spring-amqp which is also based on the mentioned `spring-messaging` API. And there are more like Spring for Apache Kafka: https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka. Spring Cloud Stream also uses some of that messaging API: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream. So, Spring JMS is just one of the samples where Spring Messaging concepts are applied.

Comment: Hi! Any advantage using spring-jms package classes over ones from spring-messaging package?

Comment: If you deal with JMS: there is nothing what would help you with JMS in the common messaging module